# Vue iFrames with Vue Router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Not sure if i'm doing something wrong or if this is a bug,

I have a simple web vue.js page running vue router with an iframe on the homepage. Without the iframe on the page it works fine when using v-link to move between pages but with the iframe I get this cross domain error when trying to move between pages.

`vue.common.js?e881:1140 Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:8080" from accessing a frame with origin "http://interactr-dev.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.`

I'm not sure if this has anything to do with it but the iframe is also running Vue (They don't bind on the same id though).

Does anyone no if this is a bug with Vue or with the way i'm doing it?

Comment: This is a cross origin problem: You seem to be mixing content from your local server and your amazon s3 server.

Comment: Yeah it's the src of the iframe is on s3. the iframe loads and plays just fine, it doesn't show the error until you trigger a page change with vue router, not sure if Vue is trying to do anything in the iframe when it does a page change and thats whats throwing the cross domain error

Comment: I don't know if it's related, but the [last release of Vue (1.0.24)](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/releases) says: `fixed regression in 1.0.23 that breaks app if the page contains iframes with different origins`

Comment: Ahh thats it. The main page was running the latest version of Vue but the iframe was running 1.0.21, I updated the version of Vue in the iframe and that's solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Vue v1.0.24 fixed a problem with iframes (thanks @Yerko). The author of this question mentioned that updating to a higher version fixed the issue.